# Access internal constructor outside the assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I reviewed the code of Specflow in github and found a tricky issue that I cannot understand.

Line 69 in https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioContext.cs

```
internal ScenarioContext(IObjectContainer scenarioContainer, ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo, ITestObjectResolver testObjectResolver)
```

Line 97~100 in https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/master/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.PluginTests/Infrastructure/WindsorPluginTests.cs

```
            var context = new ScenarioContext(
                objectContainer.Object, 
                new ScenarioInfo("", "", Array.Empty<string>(), new OrderedDictionary()), 
                new WindsorTestObjectResolver());
```

The constructor of TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioContext is internal which means it could only access in the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll.  Why it still can access in TechTalk.SpecFlow.PluginTests.Infrastructure.WindsorPluginTests class? TechTalk.SpecFlow.PluginTests.Infrastructure.WindsorPluginTests class is in TechTalk.SpecFlow.PluginTests.dll. They are in different assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [InternalsVisibleTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0). This enables access to internal types, methods, etc. to every object calling from the authorized assembly.

In https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/AssemblyAttributes.cs the assembly TechTalk.SpecFlow is decorated with some of this attributes, exposing all the internal methods to the listed assemblies:

- TechTalk.SpecFlow.RuntimeTests
- TechTalk.SpecFlow.PluginTests

It's a very common and useful technique used to test methods that should not be accessible to anyone, but that need to be tested.